# Test execution with multiple classes in TestNG using threads

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I'm trying to run multiple classes in my TestNG project but one of classes always fail.

**AbstractTest.java** *(the sampleTest1 and sampleTest2 classes only contain one-one @Test with a get() method)*

```
public class AbstractTest {

  private List<WebDriver> webDriverPool = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<WebDriver>());
  private ThreadLocal<WebDriver> driverThread;

  @BeforeTest
  public void beforeTest()
  {
    this.driverThread = new ThreadLocal<WebDriver>() {
      @Override
      protected WebDriver initialValue() {
        final WebDriver webDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
        webDriverPool.add(webDriver);
        return webDriver;
      }
    };
  }

  @AfterTest
  public void afterTest() {
    for (WebDriver driver : this.webDriverPool) {
      driver.quit();
    }
  }

  public WebDriver getDriver() {
    return this.driverThread.get();
  }

}
```

**testng.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite thread-count="11" name="testSuite" parallel="tests">
    <test name="Test1" group-by-instances="true">
        <classes>
            <class name="test.sample.sampleTest1" />
            <class name="test.sample.sampleTest2" />
        </classes>
    </test> <!-- Test1 -->
</suite> <!-- testSuite -->
```

The problem is that one of the Thread don't see the WebDriver and it returns with null and will fail. I know that if I change ThreadLocal to static it will work but it causes more problems if I run my tests in parallel, what is my goal :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: getDriver() should be static and synchronized.of course only if u want to share it betwen classes with the same state. If you need separate classes and driver then you can also have static method but you need setter to set new state each per test class.

Comment: Could you please write, what do I have to modify? I tried what you wrote but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Use other approach of using ThreadLocal. e.g. kind of a thread-safe singleton implementation can help:

```
public class DriverSession
{
    private static ThreadLocal<DriverSession> instance = new ThreadLocal<DriverSession>();
    private WebDriver                  driver;

    public static DriverSession getInstance()
    {
        if (null == instance.get())
        {
            instance.set(new Proxy1());
        }
        return instance.get();
    }

    protected DriverSession()
    {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }

    public WebDriver getDriver()
    {
        return this.driver;
    }
}
```

That's how I do it. So in order to access current driver instance use:

```
DriverSession.getInstance().getDriver().get("http://google.com");
```

Comment: Maybe my question is misunderstandable. So... I would like to run tests in parallel which contains different classes. I set up the browser in the @BeforeTest because I would like to run the classes in the same browser sequentially but not in parallel. The reason why I'm using group-by-instances is that I'm using the same priorities for the methods inside the classes (for example every class have priority=1 methods) and without this parameter there will be problems with that.

Comment: Yes, I didn't get what you meant. In that case you need something which will allow to share the instance between classes inside your thread. Please, see updated answer.